# Local uniform convergence of integrals involving determinants

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, weak-convergence

Assume that $J=J\big(x_1,x_2\big)$ is a locally bounded function from $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ and $J_n=J_n\big(x_1,x_2\big)$ is a sequence of functions from $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ that locally uniformly converges to $J$.

Fix $B$ a bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and $\ell\in\mathbb N$. I want to show that the following convergence holds
\begin{equation}\label{eq:conv_goal}
  \int_{B^\ell} \det\left(\left[J_n\big(x_i,x_j\big)\right]_{1\leq i,j \leq \ell}\right)
  dx_1\dots dx_\ell
  \to
  \int_{B^\ell} \det\left(\left[J\big(x_i,x_j\big)\right]_{1\leq i,j \leq \ell}\right)
  dx_1\dots dx_\ell.
 \end{equation}
We start by fixing $\bar x\in B^\ell$.
Since by assumption $J_n$ locally uniformly converges to $J$ and $J$ is locally bounded, there exists a neighborhood $U_{\bar x}$ of $\bar x$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:dom}
  \det\left(\left[J_n\big(x_i,x_j\big)\right]_{1\leq i,j \leq \ell}\right)\leq \prod_{j=1}^\ell \Big(\sum_{i=1}^\ell J_n\big(x_i,x_j)^2\Big)^{1/2}\leq C,  \quad\forall (x_i)_{1\leq i\leq \ell}\in U_{\bar x},
 \end{equation}
where in the first inequality we used Hadamard's inequality.
Now note that since $J_n$ locally uniformly converges to $J$, then for every fixed $(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq \ell}\in B^\ell$,
\begin{equation*}
  \det\left(\left[J_n\big(x_i,x_j\big)\right]_{1\leq i,j \leq \ell}\right)
  \to \det\left(\left[J\big(x_i,x_j\big)\right]_{1\leq i,j \leq \ell}\right)
 \end{equation*}
Now I want to use dominated convergence to conclude but my dominations holds only locally. Any help to conclude the proof?

Comment: How about covering $B$ by small balls where uniform convergence takes place?

Comment: But then the constant $C$ bounding the determinant would be different for each ball no?